# Visualizar taxonomias en publicaciones con estilo

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy intentando visualizar en una publicación el resultado de una taxonomia elegida, pero estoy trabada:

```
<? php the_terms ($ post-> ID, 'localidad', 'Localidades:', '/ '); ?>
```

Pero me aparecen uno debajo del otro y yo deseo que me aparezca en la misma linea. y no se me ocurre donde puedo indicar que  ** Localidades: ** sea en negrita.

¿podran ayudarme? Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the_terms te mostrara las taxonomias como enlaces (etiquetas  que por defecto son inline), si se te muestra una debajo de otra es o porque el contenedor de dichos enlaces necesita ser mas ancho o porque algun CSS esta modificando las etiquetas para que sean `display: block;`

El tercer parametro soporta HTML, por lo que puedes poner `'<b>Localidades:</b>'`

Comment: Gracias! ¿hay forma de anular el link?

Comment: O sea, que solo salgan los nombres de las taxonomias pero no enlacen a ningun sitio?

<?php 
 $terms = get_the_terms ($post->id, 'localidad');
 $localidad_nombres = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'name'); 
 $localidad_yo = implode(", ", $localidad_nombres);
?>

<span><?php echo $localidad_yo; ?></span>

Comment: muchas gracias!